# MySQL duplicate row, and add some new data

Tags: mysql

I have found a lot of answers into how to duplicate a row.  It is easy enough, however I haven't seem to have found any examples like what I am looking for.  I need to duplicate parts of a row, and add some new data as well.

So duplicating a row:

```
Insert Into TableName (user, course,title) 
Select user, 11 From TableName Where course=6;
```

How would I duplicate the row, and add my own information to title?  Would I put a comma after the select statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it the same way you are modifying information for the course - just provide a hard-coded value:

```
Insert Into TableName (user, course, title)
Select user, 11, 'My New Title' From TableName Where course=6;
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It doesn't matter that the data doesn't come from `TableName`, so long as a value is provided for the field `title` that you're inserting into.

Comment: This worked great, thanks!  I was afraid since it was within a select statement it wouldn't be passing information